# How do I specify a column header for pandas groupby result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need to group by and then return the values of a column in a concatenated form. While I have managed to do this, the returned dataframe has a column name 0. Just 0. Is there a way to specify what the results will be.

```
    all_columns_grouped = all_columns.groupby(['INDEX','URL'], as_index  = False)['VALUE'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

The resulting groupby object has the headers

```
    INDEX | URL | 0
```

The results are in the 0 column.
While I have managed to rename the column using

```
   .rename(index=str, columns={0: "variant"}) this seems very in elegant.
```

Any way to provide a header for the column? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpliest is remove `as_index  = False` for return `Series` and add parameter `name` to [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

Sample:

```
all_columns = pd.DataFrame({'VALUE':['a','s','d','ss','t','y'],
                   'URL':[5,5,4,4,4,4],
                   'INDEX':list('aaabbb')})

print (all_columns)
  INDEX  URL VALUE
0     a    5     a
1     a    5     s
2     a    4     d
3     b    4    ss
4     b    4     t
5     b    4     y

all_columns_grouped = all_columns.groupby(['INDEX','URL'])['VALUE'] \
                                 .apply(' '.join) \
                                 .reset_index(name='variant')

print (all_columns_grouped)
  INDEX  URL variant
0     a    4       d
1     a    5     a s
2     b    4  ss t y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `agg` when applied to a column (`VALUE` in this case) to assign column names to the result of a function.

```
# Sample data (thanks @jezrael)
all_columns = pd.DataFrame({'VALUE':['a','s','d','ss','t','y'],
                   'URL':[5,5,4,4,4,4],
                   'INDEX':list('aaabbb')})

# Solution
>>> all_columns.groupby(['INDEX','URL'], as_index=False)['VALUE'].agg(
        {'variant': lambda x: ' '.join(x)})
  INDEX  URL variant
0     a    4       d
1     a    5     a s
2     b    4  ss t y
```

Comment: If remove `as_index=False` get warning, not sure if this is good approach - check this http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming

Comment: @jezrael Yes, this method appears set for deprecation.  Warnings start to appear in v0.20.1.  I used an older version to test it and didn't get the warning.

Comment: time to upgrade ;)